# Exception while parsing command line options using args4j

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-interface

I am trying to work with args4j. I created a dummy project that contains one single command line option called 'enableAuth'. See [Features.java](https://github.com/seshumadhav/java-projects/blob/master/args4j-demo/src/com/args4j/demo/Features.java).

I tried to run this in eclipse with run configuration > program arguments as `--enableAuth=true`, `-enableAuth=true`, `-enableAuth true` etc., But none of them work for me. I run into CmdLineException always.

Any help is appreciated. Github project: https://github.com/seshumadhav/java-projects/tree/master/args4j-demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For boolean fields I don't think we are suppose to give values(i.e. true/false). Just pass the argument as a flag

java XXX.java -enableAuth

If the field was non-boolean than it would have expected a value.

Comment: Ah, that worked like a charm. It's kinda weird though that it doesnot entertain --isMyFlagEnabled=false sort of usage. Also, this puts another question to me - What is the significance of required attribute on such a boolean ?